# Where did I go wrong in using wine to download popcorn-time

Tags: wine, dependencies, crash, playback

I downloaded wine 2.0 with the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-staging

sudo apt-get install winehq-staging wine-devel

sudo su

winecfg
```

I downloaded Popcorn-Time.0.3.10 from popcorn-time.sh and got the windows 7 version.

Used wine Popcorn-Time-0.3.10-Setup.exe to install.

After install I open with wine Popcorn-Time.exe in linux terminal.

The app opens and loads good.

I try to select a video to watch and it crashes before download with the message below.

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on execute access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x00000000).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:00000000 ESP:00efe3b8 EBP:00efe424 EFLAGS:00010216(  R- --  I   -A-P- )
 EAX:00000000 EBX:00efe618 ECX:00efe394 EDX:c000007a
 ESI:00000000 EDI:00efe6b8
Stack dump:
0x00efe3b8:  00435c34 00efe6b8 00000000 00efe618
0x00efe3c8:  00000001 00000000 0013e188 00efe618
0x00efe3d8:  00439511 00efe3f4 00000000 004ab004
0x00efe3e8:  000000a8 00000000 00000000 0000000f
0x00efe3f8:  00000000 00137330 00efe424 00435b57
0x00efe408:  00efe41c 00efe6b8 00efe618 00000000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x00000000 (0x00efe424)
  1 0x004359e3 in popcorn-time (+0x359e2) (0x00efe508)
  2 0x0042c630 in popcorn-time (+0x2c62f) (0x00efe854)
  3 0x0047597f in popcorn-time (+0x7597e) (0x00efe878)
  4 0x7bc94175 in ntdll (+0x84174) (0x00efe8d8)
  5 0x7bc93f29 in ntdll (+0x83f28) (0x00efe918)
  6 0x7bc95710 in ntdll (+0x8570f) (0x00efe9c8)
  7 0x7bc85f6c call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x00efe9f8)
  8 0x7bc8906d call_thread_func+0xfc() in ntdll (0x00efeaf8)
  9 0x7bc85f4a RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x00efeb18)
  10 0x7bc90f9f in ntdll (+0x80f9e) (0x00eff368)
  11 0xf7527295 start_thread+0xe4() in libpthread.so.0 (0x00eff428)
  12 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  13 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  14 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  15 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  16 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  17 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  18 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  19 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  20 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  21 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  22 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  23 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  24 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  25 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  26 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  27 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  28 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  29 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  30 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  31 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  32 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  33 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  34 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  35 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  36 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  37 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  38 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  39 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  40 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  41 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  42 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  43 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  44 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  45 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  46 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  47 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  48 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  49 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  50 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  51 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  52 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  53 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  54 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  55 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  56 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  57 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  58 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  59 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  60 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  61 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  62 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  63 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  64 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  65 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  66 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  67 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  68 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  69 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  70 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  71 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  72 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  73 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  74 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  75 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  76 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  77 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  78 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  79 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  80 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  81 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  82 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  83 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  84 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  85 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  86 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  87 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  88 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  89 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  90 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  91 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  92 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  93 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  94 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  95 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  96 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  97 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  98 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  99 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  100 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  101 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  102 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  103 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  104 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  105 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  106 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  107 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  108 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  109 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  110 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  111 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  112 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  113 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  114 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  115 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  116 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  117 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  118 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  119 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  120 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  121 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  122 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  123 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  124 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  125 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  126 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  127 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  128 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  129 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  130 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  131 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  132 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  133 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  134 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  135 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  136 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  137 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  138 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  139 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  140 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  141 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  142 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  143 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  144 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  145 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  146 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  147 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  148 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  149 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  150 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  151 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  152 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  153 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  154 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  155 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  156 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  157 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  158 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  159 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  160 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  161 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  162 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  163 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  164 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  165 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  166 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  167 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  168 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  169 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  170 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  171 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  172 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  173 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  174 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  175 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  176 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  177 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  178 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  179 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  180 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  181 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  182 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  183 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  184 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  185 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  186 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  187 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  188 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  189 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  190 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  191 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  192 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  193 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  194 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  195 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  196 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  197 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  198 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  199 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  200 0xf7450eee __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x00000000: -- no code accessible --
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (59 modules)
PE    400000-  500000   Export          popcorn-time
PE   1c20000- 1c83000   Deferred        nw_elf
ELF 7b400000-7b7e5000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b410000-7b7e5000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcff000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcff000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7e479000-7e49d000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e480000-7e49d000   \               imm32
PE  7e49d000-7e4b1000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-obs
PE  7e4a0000-7e4b1000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-obsC:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-localization-obsolete-l1-2-0.dll
ELF 7e4b1000-7e4c5000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-1<
PE  7e4c0000-7e4c5000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-1
ELF 7e4c5000-7e4d9000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0<el
PE  7e4d0000-7e4d9000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0
PE  7e4d9000-7e4ee000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-
PE  7e4e0000-7e4ee000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1.dll
ELF 7e4ee000-7e502000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1<el
PE  7e4f0000-7e502000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
ELF 7e502000-7e516000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0<elf
PE  7e510000-7e516000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
ELF 7e516000-7e64f000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e530000-7e64f000   \               ole32
ELF 7e64f000-7e782000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e670000-7e782000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e782000-7e79f000   Deferred        jsproxy<elf>
  \-PE  7e790000-7e79f000   \               jsproxy
ELF 7e79f000-7e7db000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  7e7b0000-7e7db000   \               winhttp
ELF 7e7db000-7e85b000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e7f0000-7e85b000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e85b000-7e914000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7e860000-7e914000   \               winmm
ELF 7e914000-7ea43000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e920000-7ea43000   \               gdi32
ELF 7ea43000-7eb9a000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea60000-7eb9a000   \               user32
ELF 7eb9a000-7ec12000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ebb0000-7ec12000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7ec12000-7eed4000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7ec20000-7eed4000   \               shell32
ELF 7eed4000-7ef4c000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eee0000-7ef4c000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ef4c000-7ef5f000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ef5f000-7ef6c000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ef6c000-7ef87000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef87000-7ef91000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7ef91000-7efe6000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe6000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f732d000-f734a000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF f7365000-f736a000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f736a000-f7520000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f7521000-f753e000   Dwarf           libpthread.so.0
ELF f7544000-f7558000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1<e
PE  f7550000-f7558000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1
ELF f7558000-f7727000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7729000-f774e000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f774e000-f774f000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000c services.exe
    00000037    0
    00000036    0
    00000032    0
    0000000e    0
    0000000d    0
00000012 explorer.exe
    00000016    0
    00000013    0
00000030 winedevice.exe
    0000003a    0
    00000035    0
    00000034    0
    00000031    0
00000059 Popcorn-Time.exe
    ["C:\users\dwight\Local Settings\Application Data\Popcorn-Time\Popcorn-Time.exe"]
    000000d6    0
    000000a3    0
    000000a1    0
    000000a0    0
    0000009d    0
    0000009c    0
    00000082    0
    00000080    0
    0000007f    0
    0000007e    0
    0000007d    0
    0000007c    0
    0000007b    0
    0000007a    0
    00000079    0
    00000078    0
    00000077    0
    00000076    0
    00000075    0
    00000074    0
    00000073    0
    00000072    0
    00000071    0
    00000070    0
    0000006f    0
    0000006e    0
    0000006d    0
    0000006c    0
    0000006b    0
    0000006a    0
    00000069    0
    00000068    0
    00000067    0
    00000066    0
    00000065    0
    0000005a    0
0000005b (D) C:\users\dwight\Local Settings\Application Data\Popcorn-Time\Popcorn-Time.exe
    ["C:\users\dwight\Local Settings\Application Data\Popcorn-Time\Popcorn-Time.exe" --type=crashpad-handler /prefetch:7 "--database=C:\users\dwight\Local Settings\Application Data\Chromium\User Data\Crashpad" --annotation=channel=unknown --annotation=plat=Win32 --annotation=prod=nwjs --annotation=ver=-devel --handshake-handle=0x34]
    00000088    0 <==
    00000087    0
    00000064    0
    00000063    0
    00000062    0
    00000061    0
    00000060    0
    0000005f    0
    0000005e    0
    0000005d    0
    0000005c    0
000000d0 explorer.exe
    000000d5    0
    000000d4    0
    000000d3    0
    000000d2    0
    000000d1    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-2.4 (Staging)
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.10.18
```

Comment: https://get.popcorntime.sh/build/Popcorn-Time-0.3.10-Linux-64.tar.xz popcorn times is available for linux

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried Linux 3.10 and 3. 9 Both of them download movie half way and crash before complete download. I am trying to find a version of Popcorn-Time that downloads a video(series or movie) and plays it to completion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need wine fot this...

First use this commands in case you've tryed to install it before:

`sudo rm -Rf /opt/popcorntime`

`sudo rm -Rf /usr/bin/Popcorn-Time`

`sudo rm -Rf /usr/share/applications/popcorntime.desktop`

then, if you're on a 64 bit system download the file:

`wget https://get.popcorntime.sh/build/Popcorn-Time-0.3.10-Linux-64.tar.xz -O popcorntime.tar.xz`

Now, create a folder for the program:

`sudo mkdir /opt/popcorntime`

then, extract the files to this new folder using this:

`sudo tar Jxf popcorntime.tar.xz -C /opt/popcorntime/`

And there you go, now you can run the program using the command: 
 `/opt/popcorntime/Popcorn-Time`

Enjoy it!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this out. With previous popcorn-time applications movies download half way then the app crashes, any suggestions.